adcli - How to join domain with hostname longer than 20 characters?
I'm trying to join my domain, but the server joining has a hostname longer than 20 characters which apparently is too long for the samAccountName-parameter in AD. The join request itself uses adcli to join the domain, but the entire setup is realized with sssd.
The previous setup with pbis-open just worked with longer hostnames, but I have no details on how or why.
Below is the output of me trying to join the domain from the server. The same command set works fine on a server with less than 20 characters in its hostname.
root@server-1-long-hostname:~# /usr/sbin/adcli join --verbose --domain domain.example.org --domain-realm DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.ORG --domain-controller 10.0.0.1 --host-fqdn server-1-long-hostname.domain.example.org --computer-ou OU=Linux,OU=Servers,OU=MyOrg,DC=domain,DC=example,DC=org --computer-name server-1-long-hostname --login-type user --login-user admuser --user-principal=host/server-1-long-hostname.domain.example.org@DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.ORG 
 * Using fully qualified name: server-1-long-hostname.domain.example.org
 * Using domain name: domain.example.org
 * Using computer account name: server-1-long-hostname
 * Using domain realm: domain.example.org
 * Sending NetLogon ping to domain controller: 10.0.0.1
 * Received NetLogon info from: dcserver.domain.example.org
 * Wrote out krb5.conf snippet to /tmp/adcli-krb5-ABCDEF/krb5.d/adcli-krb5-conf-0DAKN9
 * Authenticated as user: admuser@DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.ORG
 * Using GSS-SPNEGO for SASL bind
 * Looked up short domain name: DOMAIN
 * Looked up domain SID: S-1-5-21-123123123-123123123-123123123
 * Using fully qualified name: server-1-long-hostname.domain.example.org
 * Using domain name: domain.example.org
 * Using computer account name: server-1-long-hostname
 * Using domain realm: domain.example.org
 * Enrolling computer name: server-1-long-hostname
 * With user principal: host/server-1-long-hostname.domain.example.org@DOMAIN.EXAMPLE.ORG
 * Generated 120 character computer password
 * Using keytab: FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
 * Computer account for server-1-long-hostname$ does not exist
 ! Couldn't find a computer container in the ou, creating computer account directly in: OU=Linux,OU=Servers,OU=MyOrg,DC=domain,DC=example,DC=org
 * Calculated computer account: CN=server-1-long-hostname,OU=Linux,OU=Servers,OU=MyOrg,DC=domain,DC=example,DC=org
 * Encryption type [3] not permitted.
 * Encryption type [1] not permitted.
 ! Couldn't create computer account: CN=server-1-long-hostname,OU=Linux,OU=Servers,OU=MyOrg,DC=domain,DC=example,DC=org: 00000523: SysErr: DSID-031A1242, problem 22 (Invalid argument), data 0

adcli: joining domain domain.example.org failed: Couldn't create computer account: CN=server-1-long-hostname,OU=Linux,OU=Servers,OU=MyOrg,DC=domain,DC=example,DC=org: 00000523: SysErr: DSID-031A1242, problem 22 (Invalid argument), data 0

root@server-1-long-hostname:~#

How can I get this, and other, server to join the domain with a hostname longer than 20 characters?

no details on how or why. probably ignored the characters after 20. This is also not uncommon on Macs...
